# Rails Always adding nested form in Recipe-Ingredient Relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Currently I have two models, Recipe and Ingredient which are linked through a has_many belongs_to relationship.

In my Recipe Form View, I have the following code:

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for :ingredients do |ingredient| %>
    <%= render 'ingredient_fields', f: ingredient %>
  <% end %>
  <div class="links">
    <%= link_to_add_association 'Add Ingredient', f, :ingredients, class: "btn btn-default add-button" %>
```

and for the _ingredient_fields.html.erb

```
.form-inline.clearfix
.nested-fields
= f.input :name, input_html: {class: "form-input form-control"}
= f.input :quantity, input_html: {class: "form-input form-control"}
= link_to_remove_association 'Remove', f, class: "form-button btn btn-default"
```

However, whenever I try and edit the recipe, it automatically re-adds all of the ingredients. For example, if the Recipe was called "Arnold Palmer" ingredients were Lemonade and Ice Tea, it would display each ingredient once. However, as soon as I enter my "edit" view, even if I do not change anything, when I return to the view, it will list Lemonade twice and Ice Tea twice. How can I prevent it from readding the ingredients when in the edit view?

The display code for reference:

```
<ul>
<% @recipe.ingredients.each do |x| %>
<li><%= (x.quantity * @recipe.rating) %> oz <%= x.name  %> </li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

EDIT: The controller after adding the :id param. It no longer adds duplicate ingredients, but I am still unable to remove ingredients.

```
def recipe_params 
  params.require(:recipe).permit(:name, :rating, :visible, :instructions, :description, :abv, ingredients_attributes: [ :id, :name, :quantity ])
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your controller, I think you didn't add the `ingredient.id` to your strong parameters.

If you don't add the id's to the strong parameters white list, Rails will think you want to add new ingredients instead of update the existing ones.

You should have something like this, note the `:id` parameter

```
def recipe_params
    params.require(:recipe).permit(ingredients_attributes: [:id, :name])
end
```

Comment: Thank you. This solved the issue of it readding the same ingredients. However, it still does not allow me to removed ingredients from the recipe.

Comment: According to http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html you need to add a field (checkbox) with name _destroy and :allow_destroy option for accepts_nested_attributes_for: